# Question about Taylor expansion and derivatives

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

This is a basic question about the nature of derivatives in the context of Taylor expansions.

Say I expand a function $f(x', y)$ around the point $x'=x$. $y$ is a set of other coordinates.

I will get
\begin{equation}
f(x',y) = f(x,y) + (x'-x) (\partial_{x'}f(x',y))|_{x'=x} + \ldots
\end{equation}

Now let's focus on the second term. I would have to take the partial derivative of $f(x',y)$ with respect to $x'$ and then evaluate everything at $x'=x$.
Can this term simply be written as $ (\partial_{x'}f(x',y))|_{x'=x} = \partial_x f(x,y)$?

The reason I am confused is because I recently saw an example where the above operation seems to be carried out. And I am not sure if the above is a valid step?

A simple example suggests that it is: Let $f(x')=x'^2 + x'$. Now,

\begin{equation}
(\partial_{x'}(x'^2 + x'))|_{x=x'} =(2x'+1)|_{x'=x} = 2x+1.
\end{equation}

If we do the evaluation before taking the derivative we get

\begin{equation}
(\partial_{x'}(x'^2 + x'))|_{x=x'} = (\partial_{x}(x^2 + x))= 2x+1
\end{equation}

Does this mean that it does not matter in what order I do an evaluation vs another operation?

Comment: The way you write it, you still have a variable $x$, so it does not matter. But what if you want to expand around $x'=0$? What is $\partial_0(0^2+0)$?

Comment: moreover your substitution x'=x is a linear one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why $(\partial_{x'}f(x',y))|_{x'=x}$ is the same as $\partial_{x}f(x,y)$ is because you're just renaming variables. In the first partial derivative, the index $x'$ in $\partial_{x'}$ is telling you that in the expression $\partial_{x'}f(x',y)$ you're deriving by the first variable. In the second expression $\partial_{x}f(x,y)$ the same situation occurs - the $x$ in the index still tells you that you should derive your function in respect to the first variable (since they have the same name).

Take now for example the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y$. Let's look at the two following cases:

1. $(\partial_{x'}f(x',y))|_{x'=x^2+1}=(2x')|_{x'=x^2+1}=2x^2+2$
2. $(\partial_{x'}f(x',y))|_{x'=x^2+1}=\partial_{x}((x^2+1)^2+y)=\partial_{x}(x^4+2x^2+1+y)=4x^3+4x$

Here you don't get the same result. As Dr. Richard Klitzing said, the substitution that I made here is not linear. Keep in mind, the second case is not correct! The way it's written you need to derive first and then substitute!